# Декодировка письма Gmail Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, imap

Хочу прочитать последнее письмо которое мне пришло на прочту с помощью imaplib, Но тема и текст письма зашифрованы, как расшифровать?
Текст что мне выдает и сам код снизу

```
('none none', 'Тут почта от кого пришла')
Wed, 28 Jul 2021 00:36:09 +0300
=?UTF-8?B?0J3QvtCy0LDRjyDQt9Cw0Y/QstC60LAg4oSWMzY3ODk0MTE=?=
<CAAzzXJgMW=tfFRHKs+5eBujcphzfs67pBv5bnNPfO58deAJrFA@mail.gmail.com>
```

Код

```
import imaplib
import email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('***', '***')
 
mail.list()
mail.select("inbox")

result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
 
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
 
result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
raw_email = data[0][1]
raw_email_string = raw_email.decode()

email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

print(email.utils.parseaddr(email_message['From']))
print(email_message['Date'])
print(email_message['Subject'])
print(email_message['Message-Id'])
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать политику [default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html#email.policy.default) в [message_from_string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string) ([согласно ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55210089/5909792))

```
from email import policy
...

email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string, policy=policy.default)
```

Пример:

```
from email import policy
import email

raw_email_string = """\
From: aperson@dom.ain
To: bperson@dom.ain
Subject: the next line has a space on it
\x20
Date: Mon, 8 Apr 2002 15:09:19 -0400
Message-ID: spam

Here's the message body
"""

email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string, policy=policy.default)
print(email.utils.parseaddr(email_message['From']))
print(email_message['Date'])
print(email_message['Subject'])
print(email_message['Message-Id'])
print(email_message.get_payload())
```

Результат:

```
('', 'aperson@dom.ain')
Mon, 08 Apr 2002 15:09:19 -0400
the next line has a space on it 
spam
Here's the message body
```

Comment: Тема письма показывается благодаря вашему ответу, спасибо.
Но текст письма не показывает :с

Comment: @UkaUkaa, а добавьте в вопрос `raw_email_string`, попробую поиграться с ним

Comment: @UkaUkaa, т.е. при `print(email_message.get_payload())` не выводит текст?

Comment: Выводит объект а не текст
` [ <email.message.EmailMessage object at 0x0000012DBA5CAC10>, <email.message.EmailMessage object at 0x0000012DBA5CAAF0> ] `

Comment: Вам нужно проверять что вернулось и если список, то перебрать его. В описании https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload указано, что если is_multipart(), то вернется список из Message, иначе строка. А в описании Message есть метод для получения строки: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.as_string. Тогда я бы попробовал такое для списка:, `payload = email_message.get_payload()` + `print('\n'.join(m.as_string() for m in payload))`